# Kanan and Ezra's (and Ashoka's) Fate before Episode V?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

I think one of the most lingering questions that has been around since before even the first episode of Rebels aired is this; if there are Jedi during the time between III and IV, then if they continue on living past Empire and Jedi the words of Yoda have no meaning; because then how can the final words of Yoda, "The last of the Jedi will you be", have any real gravity?  Since watching Rebels, I know that I personally have come to accept this as essential to the entire story line.

You watch these movies and there is weight to the fact that you are watching Luke and Vader, father and son, the last of their respective kinds (sans emperor) duke it out for the fate of the entire galaxy...  Knowing that there could be other Jedi destroys that weight and removes importance to the movies.  Will we be seeing the death of the Jedi Ezra, Kanan, and Ashoka?

Comment: Since neither Kanam nor Ashoka ever became Jedi Knights, Yoda may not consider them true Jedis.

Comment: Voting to close due to the future works policy.

Comment: Voting to reopen as it no longer future works and can be answered to a reasonable degree of satisfaction.

Comment: @JeremyFrench the death of Ezra and Ahsoka is still opinion based, as we don't now if we will be seeing that death.

Comment: We know Ahsoka is not dead dead, as we see her after The Battle of Yavin. It is assumed the Ezra is still alive (somewhere). But it is not opinion that neither of them are Jedi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually answered in Episode III novelization by Matthew Stover.

There's pretty much no difference to whether there are other Jedi aside from Luke and Leia and Yoda and Obi-Wan, according to Yoda, because the **Old Jedi Order was inadequate to combat the New Model Sith as repersented by Sidious and Anakin**. Old Jedi failed structurally, not because there weren't enough of them.

> It came when the avatar of light resolved into the lineage of the Jedi; when the lineage of the Jedi refined into one single Jedi.
>
> It came when Yoda found himself alone against the dark.
>
> In that lightning-speared tornado of feet and fists and blades and bashing machines, his vision finally pierced the darkness that had clouded the Force.
>
> **Finally, he saw the truth.**
>
> This truth: that he, the avatar of light, Supreme Master of the Jedi Order, the fiercest, most implacable, most devastatingly powerful foe the darkness had ever known …
>
> ... **just—  didn’t—  have it.**
>
> **He’d never had it. He had lost before he started.
>
> **He had lost before he was born.**
>
> The Sith had changed. The Sith had grown, had adapted, had invested a thousand years’ intensive study into every aspect of not only the Force but Jedi lore itself, in preparation for exactly this day. The Sith had remade themselves.
>
> They had become new.
>
> While the Jedi—
>
> **The Jedi had spent that same millennium training to re-fight the last war.**
>
> **The new Sith could not be destroyed with a lightsaber; they could not be burned away by any torch of the Force**. The brighter his light, the darker their shadow. How could one win a war against the dark, when war itself had become the dark’s own weapon?

Later, he meditates on that when waiting for Padme to give birth:

> “Too old I was,” Yoda said. “Too rigid. Too arrogant to see that the old way is not the only way. **These Jedi, I trained to become the Jedi who had trained me, long centuries ago—but those ancient Jedi, of a different time they were. Changed, has the galaxy. Changed, the Order did not**—because let it change, I did not.”

---

And radio version of Star Wars had Obi-Wan acknowledge the same idea to Luke:

> We are not altogether alone in the galaxy, you and I. But I doubt that we can rely on help from others of our kind.

Answer (score 1):

This is of course rooted purely in speculation since the show still on-going, but I think we will at least see the death of Ashoka. Why? Because of Return of the Jedi. When Sidious is zapping Luke, Vader looks at Luke, then back at Sidious, then back at Luke and back again. He is clearly in conflict. (they even added in a "No!" later which is not needed since the visual speaks clear enough but I digress) - They never really payed off this conflict in Episode III. Yes, Anakin stands by while Mace Windu is killed but it isn't very dramatic other than for shock value. Anakin doesn't have a deep personal relationship with Windu. He does have great care for Ashoka though. I'm hoping we see a parallel scene with Tano getting zapped by Sidious and Vader just let's it happen. This will make the scene in Jedi resonate even more powerfully.

Comment: It appears that all the Rebels, except Kanan, but including Ahsoka, survived the Battle of Endor. Only Ezra's fate is unknown. So your assumption was wrong.